# With Javascript how would I search the first three letters in a string and see if they match "ABC"?

Tags: javascript

With Javascript how would I search the first three letters in a string and see if they match "ABC"? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a regular expression:

```
str.match(/^ABC/);
```

or using the `substring` method:

```
str.substring(0, 3) == 'ABC';
```

Comment: Hi Sinan, it is saffer to use first method?

Comment: 'Safer' in what sense? Security-wise, I do not see a problem with either. If we are talking about the availability, I believe `substring` has been available since JS 1.0 and `match` was added later in JS 1.2.

Comment: The first method is slower. I don’t know what you mean by “safer” though.

Comment: For such a simple need, its actually better to use the substring method, as it is significantly faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (/^ABC/.test(aString)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ABCDEF".match(/^ABC/)
```